# How annotation internally works in java

Tags: java, annotations

I know how to create custom annotation. But i am unable to understand how does it work internally. If i take example of spring annontation.

```
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:database.properties" }).
```

if we see internal details of @PropertySource annotation

```
@Target({ java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Repeatable(PropertySources.class)
public @interface PropertySource {
    public abstract String name();

    public abstract String[] value();

    public abstract boolean ignoreResourceNotFound();
}
```

We do not have provided any implementation here for loading property file.
Then How is it loading property file from classpath. Who is working behind the scene ?

Comment: It might help if you read [an example on creating your own annotations](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/) to see how they work behind the scenes.

Comment: An annotation doesn't do anything. It just adds metadata to classes, methods, fields, etc. The framework (Spring in this case), uses reflection, at runtime, to find the annotations on the classes, and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet.

Answer (score 2):

Really simple: framework. That is. All 'custom' annotations processed by frameworks using reflection. Only small scope of annotations are processed by compiler, such as `@Override`, `@SuppressWarnings`, `@Retention` and so on

Comment: Those are processed by the compiler, not the JVM. The JVM doesn't care about annotations afaik

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd, At whole... I don't know. I don't know on what stage this annotations processed, but in summary I just try to explain that small scope of annotations processed by compiler. Thank you for correct me.